# How can I use bucket_sequence_by_length with a (zipped) dataset of multiple components per element

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataset for which each observation has multiple components (more than standard `X`, `y`, let's say I have additional component `Z`). Each observation can have variable length, therefore I wanted to use `bucket_by_sequence_length` from `tf.data.Dataset` API. I created datasets for `X`, `Z`, `y` separately, and then I zipped them together. Here's the minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
np.random.seed(42)
X = []
Z = []
y = []
for i in range(100):
    obs_len = np.random.randint(5, 25)
    X.append(np.random.random(size=[obs_len, 4]))
    Z.append(np.random.random(size=[obs_len, 1]))
    y.append(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=[obs_len,]))

def create_generator(list_of_arrays):
    for i in list_of_arrays:
        yield i
        
X_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: create_generator(X), output_types= tf.float32, output_shapes=(None, 4))
Z_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: create_generator(Z), output_types= tf.float32, output_shapes=(None, 1))
y_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: create_generator(y), output_types= tf.float32, output_shapes=(None, ))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X_dataset, Z_dataset, y_dataset))
```

Now I wanted to `bucket_by_sequence_length` on `dataset`, but I got following error (see the excerpt):

```
   (...)
   2686     def element_to_bucket_id(*args):
   2687       """Return int64 id of the length bucket for this element."""
-> 2688       seq_length = element_length_func(*args)
   2689 
   2690       boundaries = list(bucket_boundaries)

TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Since tf complained about `element_length_func` that was defined to take one argument (a tuple of 3 elements), but received three arguments (a tuple was unrolled) I tried to change the implementation of length function:

```
def get_len(X, Z, y):
    return X.shape[0]

dataset.bucket_by_sequence_length(element_length_func=get_len,
                                  bucket_boundaries=[15],
                                  bucket_batch_sizes=[8, 8])
```

However, it was also unsuccessful and resulted in the error:

```
ValueError: Tried to convert 'y' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

Unfortunately, the tracebacks for both errors are really long so I decided to trim them, but the example should be easily reproducible.

Therefore, my question is - how can I use `bucket_by_sequence_length` when my dataset has more than one or two components?

Answer (score 0):

Just use dynamic shape `tf.shape` in `get_len` but not static one `.shape`.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(42)
X = []
Z = []
y = []
for i in range(100):
    obs_len = np.random.randint(5, 25)
    X.append(np.random.random(size=[obs_len, 4]))
    Z.append(np.random.random(size=[obs_len, 1]))
    y.append(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=[obs_len,]))

def create_generator(list_of_arrays):
    for i in list_of_arrays:
        yield i
        
X_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: create_generator(X), output_types= tf.float32, output_shapes=(None, 4))
Z_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: create_generator(Z), output_types= tf.float32, output_shapes=(None, 1))
y_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: create_generator(y), output_types= tf.float32, output_shapes=(None, ))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((X_dataset, Z_dataset, y_dataset))

def get_len(X, Z, y):
    return tf.shape(X)[0]

bucket_dataset = dataset.bucket_by_sequence_length(
    element_length_func=get_len,
    bucket_boundaries=[15],
    bucket_batch_sizes=[8, 8]
) 

next(iter(bucket_dataset))
```